# how do i parse a dtd file

Tags: c#, code-generation, dtd-parsing

I want to parse a dtd file and use the info I get from that to create some classes.  I know that I can convert it to a xsd and then parse it, but I was hoping to avoid that. Everything I find via google is to validate against a dtd.  So I guess my question is: How do I parse a dtd file using c# or are there any tools or libraries out there that I can use? I should add that I'm using visual studio 2005.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need an SGML parser: this thread should help you out: [SGML parser .NET recommendations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1148083/sgml-parser-net-recommendations)