# Recommendation for parsing HTML and SGML file

Tags: c#, .net, html, xml, sgml

I have a project that will accept inputs such as (html, sgml, xml and txt).

I have  no problem parsing the XML files and txt files, Can you please suggest some tools that I can use on parsing html or sgml files.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=c%23+html+parser

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For **HTMl Parser**, use the HTML Agilty Pack - it is an open source HTML parser for .NET.

> What is exactly the Html Agility Pack (HAP)?
>
> This is an agile HTML parser that builds a read/write DOM and supports
>   plain XPATH or XSLT (you actually don't HAVE to understand XPATH nor
>   XSLT to use it, don't worry...). It is a .NET code library that allows
>   you to parse "out of the web" HTML files. The parser is very tolerant
>   with "real world" malformed HTML. The object model is very similar to
>   what proposes System.Xml, but for HTML documents (or streams).

You can use this to query HTML and extract whatever data you wish.

For **SGML Parser**

Check out this link, SGMLReader - Convert any HTML to valid XML:

http://developer.mindtouch.com/Community/SgmlReader

Reference: [SGML parser .NET recommendations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1148083/sgml-parser-net-recommendations)

Comment: has anyone tried processing sgml files with HAP?

Answer (score 1):

For parsing HTML I can't recommend anything other then http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/ and since SGML is basicly the same but with other elements you could probaly use it for that as well.